# which one i should choose Sencha touch 2 or Phonegap

Tags: mobile, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am a beginner to mobile technologies. In my cross platform application, i have to implement push notifications for both android and ios and i like to integrate facebook & twitter authentication and use more than RSS flow.

So, my first question is that "Which is the best framework either Jquery mobile or Sencha touch 2. Which is preferable for initial stage of development???"

Second one, "What about the documentation, how has the big resource of documentation and tutorials ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The learning curve of `Sencha Touch` is very steep, inherited from `Ext JS`. You will need to invest a lot of time learning Ext JS  architecture and components. If you want to go with your own, you will throw away the whole library and you will end up doing an application similar to **PhoneGap** approach.

Architecture: **Sencha Touch** enforces an object-oriented approach. This is an advantage over PhoneGap. PhoneGap as a container and an interface for native features, does not enforce any. Of course, a similar appraoch can be done with PhoneGap using open source frameworks available on the web.

Extensibility: **PhoneGap** supports an extensive array of plugins that are umatched in any other framework. It's fairly easy to write your own as well.

Creating layouts with **Sencha Touch** components is a bit difficult than PhoneGap. You must stick with their layouts, panels, etc.

**Sencha Touch** depends radically on Javascript for creating UI. So, if you need to customize or add UI components, you need to do it in JS

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is that phongape can let me achieve all requirements mentioned in my question, i have 7 weeks for this application

Comment: Yes of course phonegap can...if possible use icenium IDE.. Check the following link for more information.... http://www.icenium.com/...where you will be having the pushplugin  and facebook authentication sample projects in it where you only be needed to do some tweaking...Do upvote if you find it useful..thanks

Comment: Thanks again, I would like more opinions if you please :D

Comment: @nomade Yeah icenium is could based environment, where they have ready made setup for phonegap+jquery mobile framework project setup. I worked in that too. But its paid one, Single dev / month basis charges

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Arun. Right now i started learning extjs and sencha touch its not easy like Jquery mobile framework. I have implemented Push notification for both android and IOS using Plush plugin. Its easy to implement, in server side i handled service using Restful webservice. If your are a beginner in Cross platform development just go with Jquery mobile. the documentation is easy to learn compared to sencha which is cold one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would like to know how can i integrate twitter an facebook authentication? is that possible ? which technologies or plugins shoukd use !?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the developer site and api.

[Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

[Twitter Api](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-twitter-api/)

Comment: You're always welcome. I think we both traveling in same boat. My current task is same as your requirement. @nomade